# DecisionTree model has Zero Accuracy

Tags: python-3.x, decision-tree

Train model on [basic dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZm2c.png) (2d array Hours_Studied and Test_Grade)
and have some predictions, but when I try to calculate accuracy_score it`s always 0.0

I guess the problem is in my array shape after splitting

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('c:/Rawdata/grade2.csv', header=0)

print ('Raw Dataset Lenght:', len(df))
print ('Raw Dataset Shape:', df.shape)
# raw dataset info output is "Raw Dataset Lenght: 9" and "Raw Dataset Shape: (9, 2)"

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = np.array(df['Hours_Studied']).reshape(-1, 1)
y = df['Test_Grade']

print ('Processed Dataset shape', X.shape, y.shape)
# Processed dataset output is "(9, 1) (9,)"
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=100)
```

instead of this

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'entropy', random_state=100)
```

new code

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
tree = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=100)
```

here no changes

```
tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
tree_pred = tree.predict(X_test)
print ('tree predicted array is', tree_pred)
# output is "[57 96 79]"
```

instead of accuracy_score

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
```

use this one

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

print('current y_test is ', '\n', y_test)
#output is  
# 1    66
#6    91
#5    81
#Name: Test_Grade, dtype: int64
```

instead of this

```
print('Accuracy tree is', accuracy_score(y_test, tree_pred))
# output is "Accuracy tree is 0.0"
```

now we have

```
print('Accuracy tree is', r2_score(y_test, tree_pred)*100)
# output is "Accuracy tree is 65.26315789473685"
```

The problem about zero accuracies is solved, Thx!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a classfication problem. You need to use a [regression tree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html) and find the mean squared error or mean average error.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped! I`ve edited my post to show the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use classification tree when you have been given discrete labels and use regression tree when you have been given continuous values like in this case.

Comment: Actually, I totally switched to Keras and NN, both for classification and regression, thx